# Interact with Web-Office (word, excel) via API?

Tags: office365, onedrive

Does MS have an API to interact with WEB office editors, document content and style?

Please note: I refer to the **web interface** for word / excel / power-point. Not the PC-installed Office.

Example use cases:

1. I would like to upload office files and share them between several users, where they can collaborate on the same document
2. Show my own dialogs to my users, inside the web editor? E.g. show dictionary value on a selected word
3. Control styling of paragraphs
4. Extract content from the document - E.g. to validate spelling

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You're looking for [Office Add-Ins](http://dev.office.com/getting-started/addins) and the [JavaScript API for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx); the 'office-js' tag here. This add-in model works in both web and desktop products though not all functions work everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that add-ons are not allowed on the web-office.
I'll surely check that

Comment: The new style of add-ins (written using web technologies) can be used; Microsoft refers to these as "Office Add-Ins" (formerly "Apps for Office"). VSTO add-ins cannot. Please mark my reply as an answer :)